# Can't get rid of labels that are generated in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I can't seem to get rid of the labels that are generated by the forms class. I found another question that seemed to have the same problem. He added "auto_id=False" to his form class and it seemed to have worked, but it didn't for me.

Here is my code as it currently stands:

```
from django import forms

class EmailSubmit (forms.Form):
auto_id=False
email = forms.EmailField(
              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'submit'}))

f = EmailSubmit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like this in your template than you can print just the fields instead of the labels aswell:

```
{{ form.field.as_widget }}
```

And for the label, if you need it for some parts:

```
{{ form.field.label_tag }}
```

Comment: that just caused everything to disappear.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that `field` should be replaced with the name of the field you are trying to print. In your that could be `email` for example.